# Single Page With Multi Form Components - Single or multiple post request to submit forms using single submit button

Tags: html, angularjs

I created a page with 3 components(divs) and each is having a html form with single submit button at the end of the page.

I would like to know what is the best design to submit the form using single submit button

1. Submit 3 forms in one post request.
2. 3 post request for submiting 3 forms.

I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the context of what you're trying to accomplish on the page. Ideally you'd have one single form with one submit button. The only reason I can see for having three forms with three submit buttons is if you do not require the other one or two forms to be submitted within the same session.
Although seeing as you're using angularjs you could collect everything into a json object and send it using `$http`

factory

```
app.factory('dataHandler',['$http', function($http){
    var handle = this;
    handle.send = function(params, actionUrl){
        return $http({
            url: actionUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            params: formParams,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    return handle;
}]);
```

controller

```
app.controller('Stage', ['dataHandler', '$scope', function(dataHandler, $scope){
   var stage = this;
   stage.processForm = function(){
      dataHandler.sendOrder(stage.formInput, 'https://url.com/script')
        .then(function (response) {
           if (response.status == 200) {
               console.log('Yay it worked');
           }
        });
   }
}]);
```

html

```
<form id="Form" name="Form" novalidate="novalidate">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="stage.formInput.thisOption" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
   <input type="text" name="address_street" ng-model="stage.formInput.details.address.street" required>
</form>
<form id="Form2" name="Form2" novalidate="novalidate">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="stage.formInput.thatOption" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
   <input type="text" name="address_street" ng-model="stage.formInput.details.address.suburb" required>
</form>
<button ng-click="stage.processForm()" name="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I am not going to have 3 submit buttons. Only single submit button, And onSubmit event I'd fire 3 independent ajax request each with their own call backs.

Comment: ah ok, I've updated the factory so you'd be able to pass a different url everytime if needed. you can still have the one submit button but then pass different json objects collected from the form to the factory function if you need to send different information to different urls.